# Codeception redirects to login for all requests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, codeception

I have just started using codeception, and i have an issue where the login script runs only for a single test. So for all the other tests where the user has to be loggedin fail.

**acceptance\core\LoginCept:**

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('login as a Admin');
$I->amOnPage('/login');
$I->fillField('email', 'test@gmail.com');
$I->fillField('password', 'test123');
$I->click('input[type=submit]');
$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/dashboard');
$I->see('Dashboard');
```

**acceptance\core\CreateUserCept:**

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Create a new user');
$I->amOnPage('/users/create');
$I->see('Please fill in the form to create a new user');
```

The LoginCept test gets passed but CreateUserCept fails and gives an error where the user is redirected to the login page.

**My question is do i have to login for each test? or does it works like a normal web based user where the user is authorized from the session?**

Secondly i think there has to be a priority system, where the logincept is called first followed by CreateUserCept and other Admin Cepts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every test is supposed to be independent, so unlike your browser session will not be persisted. If you really need to do that you can follow a suggested solution on [codeception website under "Session Snapshots"](http://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests#session-snapshots).